# Get visible view in pageController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm scrolling between different views, which i on button click from the rootViewController would like to render to a image. I'm wondering what is the best approach for this? is it possible to retrieve the visible view from my contentViewController or would i need to recreate the view somehow by getting the visible view index and then access the object equal to this index?

Comment: If you track the current view in `pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:`, and then do `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` according to the index.

Comment: Could u do a answer as a snippet not sure what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer 'is it possible to retrieve the visible view from my contentViewController', not really. You need to set a `pageIndex` property in your `CustomContentViewController`. Keep trace of it in the `didFinishAnimating` method (You can find more robust way in other posts). Or you can directly trace the `currentContentViewController`

This is just a very simple example

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    self.currentContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers!.last as! CustomContentViewController
    self.currentPageIndex = self.currentContentViewController.pageIndex
}
```

If you want to set a image, then do

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    self.currentContentViewController.imageView.image = UIImage("MyImage.png")
}
```